# Python how to update JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON file which looks like:

```
{
    "files": [
        {
            "nameandpath": "/home/test/File1.zip",
            "MD5": "e226664e39dc82749d05d07d6c3078b9",
            "name": "File1"
        },
        {
            "nameandpath": "/home/test/File2.zip",
            "MD5": "dbb11b2095c952ff1d4b284523d3085f",
            "name": "File2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I wish to update only 2 lines nameandpath and MD5, when the condition will be true.
The condition is that if the file tested is present in JSON file : i'll update the line otherwise i'll add the file with its 3 values.

```
{
    "files": [
        {
            "nameandpath": "/home/test/File1.zip",
            "MD5": "e226664e39dc82749d05d07d6c3078b9",
            "name": "File1"
        },
        {
            "nameandpath": "/home/test/File2.zip",
            "MD5": "dbb11b2095c952ff1d4b284523d3085f",
            "name": "File2"
        }
        # block added because the file tested wasn't present in json file
        {
            "nameandpath": "/home/test/File3.zip",
            "MD5": "dbb11b2095c952ff1d4b284523d3085f",
            "name": "File3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not able to update the existing lines
I haven't been able to test adding the new lines.

Can you please help me?
How can I do such thing?

My code so far:

```
# getting file name
# getting MD5 of the file

jsonfile = "/home/test/filesliste.json"

 with open(jasonfile, "r+") as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        for tp in data['files']:
            if tp['name'] == name:
                if tp['MD5'] == fileMD5:
                    print("same MD5")
                    # adding this file to json file
                else:
                    print("NOT THE same MD5")
                    # updating the file info into json file
```

Comment: You should consider using another hash-function than md5. It is considered broken. A good alternative would be SHA-2 or SHA-3.

Comment: i am using md5 because i need to test if the content of the zip files are differents or not, if they are i will keep the zip and will update the jason file otherwise i'll erase the zip file. any idea how can i do that?

Comment: @GeorgSchölly It is not broken. It is no longer considered secure enough for certain use cases (e.g. password hashing) but it’s still a fine hash function, and there is just nothing wrong with using it for data integrity checks.

Comment: @pole: I disagree. There's not advantage to using md5. It is often the case that once a cryptographic function starts to show cracks, better attacks soon follow. Knowing in what context it is still secure is non-trivial. For example password-hashing with plain SHA-3 is just as bad as with plain MD5. The weakness in this context is speed. For data-integrity, I would definitely not recommend MD5. There are no practical pre-image attacks yet, but an attacker can create collisions between multiple files, exactly what data-integrity is supposed to protect against.

Comment: @GeorgSchölly You don’t even know if there is an actual attack vector involved here. Not every hashing process is about cryptographical use. The “weakness” of speed is also a very important benefit for data integrity checks, to be able to scan files or data quickly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what exactly you're struggling with. Here's how I would structure the code, maybe this helps:

```
jsonfile = "/home/test/filesliste.json"

# read json file
with open(jsonfile) as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# find index of file or -1 if not found
index = -1
for i, tp in enumerate(data['files']):
    if tp['name'] == name and tp['MD5'] == fileMD5:
        index = i
        break

# update data
# we're lazy and just delete the old file info, then re-add it
if index >= 0:
    del data['files'][index]

tp = {
    "name": ...,
    "nameandpath": ...,
    "MD5": ...,
}
data.append(tp)

# write data back to file
with open(jsonfile) as f:
    # json.dump or something like that
```

## MD5

MD5 should not be used anymore because it is considered broken. If possible, you should replace it with SHA-2 or SHA-3 which are similar but much more secure.

Comment: @Volcano: Thanks for your edit! I did rollback it though, for me it's very strange to see a loop variable survive after the loop, so I prefer the more explicit version.

Comment: Python is dynamic language, so usually - once defined anywhere in the scope, variables survive. And loop is not a closed scope - as in compiled languages. The only exception to the rule I've encountered so far is (pun un-intended)  ... Exception in Python 3.5 - once you leave _except_ clause, you lose intercepted _Except_ object. For me your version looked slightly un-Pythonic - probably, I've been thinking Python for too long.

Comment: @volcano: How would you have written it? I thought about putting `index = -1` in front of the loop, but that's not very elegant either. I come across similar situations where there's a default value all the time and I haven't found a nice solution yet.

Comment: Actually, since PEP-8 discourages use of un-initialized loop variables outside the loop, maybe pre-setting _index_ before loop is preferred way. Just in case of _else_ clause I would have dropped re-assignment. Not a big issue, of course :) . Frankly speaking, I've been known for dissing PEP-8 before...